# Resize Canvas in GWT having a d3 svg in the div

Tags: java, gwt, d3.js, smartgwt

I am drawing 4 d3 line charts in the canvas category layer and I have a canvas and div list for categories as below

```
private ArrayList<Canvas> catCanvasList;
private ArrayList<Element> catDivList;
private int categoryCount = 0;
VLayout categoryLayer;

catCanvasList = new ArrayList<Canvas>();
catDivList = new ArrayList<Element>();
categoryCount = data.getCategories().size();

for (int i = 0; i < categoryCount; i++) {
    Canvas cat = new Canvas();
    cat.setWidth100();
    cat.setHeight100();
    categoryLayer.addMember(cat);
    catCanvasList.add(cat);
}


int a= 0;

for( final String key: data.getCategories()){

   final Canvas c = catCanvasList.get(a);
   final Element div = DOM.createDiv();
   catDivList.add(div);

   createD3Vis(div,key,data);
   a++
}
```

On window resize I redarw the d3 vis in the following way

```
 categoryLayer.addResizedHandler(new ResizedHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onResized(ResizedEvent event) {

                if (!catDivList.isEmpty() && !catCanvasList.isEmpty()) {
                    for (Element div : catDivList) {
                        div.removeFromParent(); 
                    }

                    catDivList.clear();

                    for(final Canvas c:catCanvasList){
                        c.getDOM().removeAllChildren();
                    }
                }



int a= 0;

   for( final String key: data.getCategories()){

   final Canvas c = catCanvasList.get(a);
   final Element div = DOM.createDiv();
   catDivList.add(div);

   createD3Vis(div,key,data);
   a++
}
}
});
```

But the above mentioned way does not work on resize and does not remove the div elemets 
properly.

I want to resize the canvas on window resize and redraw the d3 vis with new height and width.

Can someone point to me where I'm going wrong.